# How to rename all files and folders in a directory

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, rename

I'm using windows 10 and i want to rename all files and folders in specific directory by using **batch file**.
For example my directory is located at "D:\Test"
In the directory there are folders: "ABC000", "ABCiso"
In folder "ABC000" there are several files (without extensions) such as "ABC001","ABC002","ABC003"
I wanna rename all "ABC" in folders and files to "123".
It is highly appreciated if you can help me in this regard.

After a while I found the solution as below but it is not complete. it is highly appreciated if you can modify:

I search through google and this site so I figure it out some preliminary code (I modified the code) that will work for my problem. The code will work at local address but I wanna extend the code to run at UNC address. Due to some misunderstanding let me explain the problem again then I'm going to post the code. I wanna rename all file(s) and folder(s) in specific directory with UNC address.

Before modification I have below configuration: UNC address: \sharepoint\Sample

There are below folders in above directory: "sam000" and "samdflts" and "samdia" in "sam000" folder there are two other folders as below: "sam001" and "sam002" in "samdia" folder there are below files: "sam7009_0001" and "sam7011_0001"

after modification I wanna have below configuration: rename all folders name to: "CPL000" and "CPLdflts" and "CPLdia" and "CPL001" and "CPL002" rename all files to: "CPL7009_0001" and "CPL7011_0001"

in short I wanna replace every "sam" in files and folders to "CPL"

the code that needs modification is as below:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p NewProjectName= Please type new project name: 
set /p OldProjectName= Please type old project name:  
:: Rename folder(s) >>> (needs to be revised to all sub folder(s))
for /d %%i in ("%~dp0\*") do (
    set "name=%%~nxi" 
    ren "%%i" "%NewProjectName%!name:~3!")
:: Rename file(s) >>> (needs to be revised for UNC address)
for /r %%i in (%OldProjectName%*) do (
    set "name=%%~nxi"
    ren "%%i" "%NewProjectName%!name:~3!")
endlocal
pause
```

Would you please modify the code so it can be run in UNC address and renaming all sub folders?

Comment: You can't have multiple files with the same name in the same folder. Please clarify your question, preferably with actual examples of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: My assumption @SomethingDark, is that the OP wishes to change the directory and file names which begin with the substring `ABC` by replacing those leading three characters with the string `123`. Of course the substring isn't really `ABC` and the replacement string isn't really `123`, so the simplest of solutions will probably not work for them when they change those post answer. Vahid, this site does not write code for you, you have to write your own. This site just helps you to correct a specific and reproducible issue with the code you have already written to perform the stated task.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I'm new in batch file coding. in this days I tried to figure it out how is batch file codding works and I found some preliminary answer. I'm gonna post as a separate preliminary answer and will be highly appreciated if you can fix some bug's if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in the comments your task specification is not fully clear, however I can address the errors in your script.

The issue you ask about is UNC paths addresses and the easiest way to deal with this problem in a batch file is to use `pushd` and `popd` which do accept UNC style paths. From then on you can just use local names in the rename and it will operate with no issues.

You also have a syntax error with closing the loops (missing <kbd>)</kbd>). With these changes it looks like this:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p NewProjectName= Please type new project name: 
set /p OldProjectName= Please type old project name:  
:: Rename folder(s) >>> (needs to be revised to all sub folder(s))
pushd %~dp0
for /d %%i in ("*") do (
    set "name=%%~nxi" 
    ren "%%i" "%NewProjectName%!name:~3!"
    )
:: Rename file(s) >>> (needs to be revised for UNC address)
for /r %%i in (%OldProjectName%*) do (
    set "name=%%~nxi"
    ren "%%i" "%NewProjectName%!name:~3!"
    )
popd
endlocal
pause
```

Hopefully those are enough clues for you to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. this solution is fine for me. also I do the same by a little difference that I'm going to share as another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "Brian Tompsett" for your answer. also I do with the same way but with a little difference. this is my code for above question:

```
@echo off
title renaming all folder(s) and file(s) in current directory.
:Start
cls
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p NewProjectName= Please type new project name: 
set /p OldProjectName= Please type old project name: 

pushd %~dp0
for /D /r %%G in (%OldProjectName%*) do (
    set "name=%%~nxG" 
    ren "%%G" "%NewProjectName%!name:~3!")
for /r %%i in (%OldProjectName%*) do (
    set "name=%%~nxi"
    ren "%%i" "%NewProjectName%!name:~3!")
Popd
endlocal
set choice=
set /p choice="Do you want to restart? Press 'y' and enter for Yes: "
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='y' goto start
```